# how to get more accurate point position in an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

usually, we can get point position in an image in this way:

```
figure, imshow rice.png;
[x,y,~] = ginput(1)
```

what returned is something like this:

```
x = 121
y = 100
```

these numbers are measured by pixels, but I'd like more accurate results like:

```
x = 121.35
y = 100.87
```

any help would be appreicated!!!

Comment: why do you need this extra accuracy? if you are doing image alignment, you might want to consider `cpselect`

Comment: I am trying to do procrutes analysis and the idea is: select two sets of points from two different images and transform one set of points by rotation,scaling and translation such that it's as close as possible to the other set of points. I guess more accurate point position may help produce more satisfactory output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [imagesc](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) can be useful

```
% load example image    
Istruct = load('gatlin');    
I = Istruct.X./max(Istruct.X(:));

% display it
figure;
imagesc(I);
colormap(gray);

% get some point
[x,y]=ginput(1);

[x, y] % x and y will be double
```

Comment: amazing!!! it works great!!!just note that image may be distorted if width isn't equal to height:add `axis image` to dissolve

Answer (score 2):

For aligning / registering two images using control points you do need sub-pixel accuracy for the different control points.
Matlab has a very nice user interface for this purpose you might want to look at: [`cpselect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cpselect.html).
A nice tutorial is also available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/selecting-control-points.html).

Given two images `oim1` and `oim2` you may use `cpselect` to transform `oim2` to "fit" `oim1`:

```
>> [input_points, base_points] = cpselect(oim2, oim1, 'Wait', true);
>> T = cp2tform( input_points, base_points, 'similarity' ); % find similarity transformation
>> aim2 = tformarray( oim2, T, makeresampler('cubic','fill'), [2 1], [2 1], size(oim1(:,:,1)'), [], 0 );
```